# Adding web shortcuts with icons similar to chrome's new tab thumbnails

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, home-screen-shortcuts, motorola-droid-razr, bookmarks

I have a Droid RAZR MAXX, and there are a few shortcuts to web pages on the screen. They have been there since before the phone got ICS.

Under GB one could long tap the screen, add a shortcut, and choose a web site rather than an app. This created a shortcut with the name of the site, and the icon looked like a screen capture of the URL that the shortcut targets (like the chrome new tab page).

However in ICS I can't see way to do it, I can add a bookmark to the home screen through the browser, but the icon is different. I tried adding a bookmark through each browser, chrome, default, firefox, opera, dolphin. None of them produce this icon.

Anyone know how to do it? Or is this something that Moto threw in to the software, but didn't keep in ICS? (Though in that case why do the old icons still work?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't see how to get an individual bookmark with a thumbnail screenshot of the webpage, but there are a couple of similar things you can do with the default browser in ICS.

[image]

In the screenshot above the top row are bookmarks added to the home screen by going into the browser, opening the bookmarks list, long pressing on a bookmark and selecting "Add to Home Screen". These appear to be the using the site's "Favicon".

The next two rows are the "3x2 Bookmarks" widget, that just lists the contents of my browser's bookmarks folder. Add that by opening your apps list, selecting the Widgets tab at the top and then long pressing to drag the "3x2 Bookmarks" widget to a home screen. It then gives you a chance to pick a folder in your Bookmarks to show (you could create a new folder in bookmarks beforehand and fill that folder with only web pages that you want to show on your home screen).

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [Visual Bookmarks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kent.android.imgbookmarks), although some users have found that it no longer works for them. YMMV.