# Problem adding web app shortcut to home screen on Galaxy tablet

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

I have a Samsung GT-P7510 tablet running Android 4.0.4 and I want to add a bookmark to the home screen so I have one touch access to the web app.

Previously this same tablet was running an earlier version of Android (3.x) and I had no problem adding a web app to the home screen. I would first add the page as a bookmark and then long press the bookmark to get a menu. On the menu there was an option to add the bookmark as a shortcut on the home screen. When I did that then I am pretty sure it allowed me to specify a name for the home screen shortcut. Once I added it then it went to the home screen automatically and I could see the shortcut icon.

I recently upgraded the tablet to Android 4.0.4 and tried to do the above operation. When I do, I see these differences. When I long press a bookmark and select "Add shortcut to home" nothing seems to happen. No dialog box comes up asking me what name I want to give the shortcut. When I go to the home screen I don't see my shortcut.

Why isn't this working???

Comment: Long pressing the bookmark in the browser and selecting "Add shortcut to home" should work, but it will use the bookamrk's name and won't prompt you for a different name. Have you checked all of your homescreens? See this previous question for options adding bookmarks to the Homescreen in Android 4 and up [Adding web shortcuts with icons](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28815/)

Comment: Yes, I checked all the home pages. The shortcut to the web app is not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it have created the shortcut on a different page of the home screen? Be sure to scroll left and right to check every page.

If you still can't get that working, there's another method that should still work. Go into the app drawer (the list of apps from the home screen), then go to the **Widgets** tab. There should be a widget there called **Bookmark**. Hold it to pick it up, and then drag it to where you like on your home screen.

If you need more flexibility than that, my app **Showr** lets you create a resizable home screen shortcut with a custom icon or image. You can use any picture you like for the shortcut, and have it open the web page you set or launch an app of your choice. It can even update the picture from the web automatically: for example, if the web app is a bug tracker, and it offers an image showing how many bugs are open, you might want to use something like that as the shortcut.

[Download Showr for free from Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shadowburst.showr)

Comment: I checked all the home screen for the web app shortcut and it is not present.  When I go to the Widgets tab on my Samsung Galaxy tablet I do not see a widget called Bookmark there.

Comment: I don't have that specific device, but every device I've checked on has one. It might not be on the first page of widgets, of course.

Comment: You are correct that it is there but it was on another screen, so I didn't see it.  When I added the bookmark that way, it did add to one of the home pages.  One thing I noticed that may be the issue with the first method is that on this Galaxy tablet, the first home screen is full, even though I have like six additional blank home screens.  Could that be the reason why it refuses to add the shortcut to the home page?  If so, why wouldn't it add it to one of the blank home pages if the first home page is full?

Comment: I don't know why. Android doesn't provide a reliable way for apps to create widgets: that whole system is full of bugs. If you've managed to create your shortcut using the method I suggested, feel free to upvote and accept my answer, so that other users know your problem is solved.

Comment: Apparently I don't have the reputation to upvote your answer but I did accept it.  Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Go to web site, choose "request desktop site" on chrome settings, choose settings again, then choose "add to homescreen"

Answer (score 0):

If you've already got the webpage bookmarked, go to your app widgets ,there should be a 2nd bookmark widget ,mine had a yellow square ,it was a few widgets past the main larger bookmark widget.  Press and hold this one to add it to home screen. Then ,it should let you add your bookmarks individually, w the same size icon as other apps on your home screen. It worked for me ,anyway. :):):)